# Ag grid - How to sort column to show all null values as last?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I want to create a custom comparator to sort column asc/desc, but in both situations, I want to keep all empty (null) values at the end of the list

I use valueGetter to return a proper string value/null.

Comment: please let me know if you are facing any issue  with the below answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I think you can achieve this in 2 ways

**First: use a comparator for the column you want to use custom sort**

```
   columnDefs: [
        { 
            field: 'columnName', 
              comparator: (a, b, nodeA, nodeB, isInverted) => {
            if (a === b) {
                return 0;
              }
              // for null
             else if (a === 'null') {
                 return isInverted ?-1: 1;
             }
             else if (b === 'null') {
                 return isInverted ? 1: -1;
             }
             else { 
                return a.localeCompare(b);
             }

         }
}]
```

1. a,b: The values in the cells to be compared. Typically sorts are
   done on these values only.
2. nodeA, nodeB: The Row Nodes for the rows getting sorted. These can
   be used if more information, such as data from other columns, are
   needed for the comparison.
3. isInverted: true for Ascending, false for Descending.

**Second: use postSort mechanism, it will get called once everything is sorted**

```
     <GridOptions> {
                  postSort:  this.postSort 
                  }// add this to grid options
          
 private postSort = function(rowNodes) {
    // null value data will be sorted at the end

    function checkNull(node) {
        return node.data.Id ===  null ; // if id is column is the one we are chceking
    }

    function move(toIndex, fromIndex) {
        rowNodes.splice(toIndex, 0, rowNodes.splice(fromIndex, 1)[0]);
    }

    var nextInsertPos = rowNodes.length; //last index

    for (var i = 0; i < rowNodes.length; i++) {
        if (rowNodes[i].data && checkNull(rowNodes[i])) {
            move(nextInsertPos, i)
            nextInsertPos++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the first solution is cleaner, but it doesn't work during descending sort - I still have null values before each one.

Comment: Thank you for the update,  I have updated the answer. Ag Grid comparator behaving slightly different from normal sort. The latest  solution seems to be working for me.

Comment: And also I have taken null as string 'null' please check your data type of null  do the comparison accordingly. a === null / a === 'null'

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I was pretty close to finish it...